# How to assign the returned value from a Snowflake SQL stored procedure into variable?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a stored procedure in Snowflake that returns number of rows in a table. Here is the code for the procedure and the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CDS_EXTRACT_CHECK_ROWCOUNT(STAGE_DATABASE varchar, STAGE_SCHEMA varchar, STAGE_TABLE varchar)
RETURNS table (a int)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
    DECLARE
    stmt string;
    res resultset;
    rowcount int;
    BEGIN
        stmt := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || :STAGE_DATABASE || '.' || :STAGE_SCHEMA || '.' || :STAGE_TABLE || ';'; 
        res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt);
        RETURN TABLE(res);
    END
;
```

[image: Result after calling the procedure]

I want to execute this stored procedure within another procedure and store the returned value to a variable:

```
rowcount := CALL CDS_EXTRACT_CHECK_ROWCOUNT(:STAGE_DATABASE, :STAGE_SCHEMA, :STAGE_TABLE);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi - just wondering why you are returning a single integer value as a table and also why you are using a procedure, rather than a function, to calculate and return a value?

Comment: @NickW I need to be able to calculate this row count for variable databases/schemas/tables hence the use of a stored procedure. I thought that only stored procedures could accommodate the dynamic SQL while also returning a single value. As for returning the table, I do not know how to return a single value from a  dynamic SQL query which is why I elected to use a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RESULT_SCAN to read the value returning from your stored procedure:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

For example:

```
...
CALL CDS_EXTRACT_CHECK_ROWCOUNT(:STAGE_DATABASE, :STAGE_SCHEMA, :STAGE_TABLE);
select $1 into :rowcount from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CDS_EXTRACT_CHECK_ROWCOUNT(
    STAGE_DATABASE varchar, 
    STAGE_SCHEMA varchar, 
    STAGE_TABLE varchar
)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
    table_path string;
    rowcount int;
BEGIN
    table_path := :STAGE_DATABASE || '.' || :STAGE_SCHEMA || '.' || :STAGE_TABLE;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :rowcount  FROM identifier(:table_path); 

    return :rowcount;
END
;
```